# How to change the for loop in my code to give me an additional column in my dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing a semantic search to find the closest synonym in two text columns, in two different dataframes.

The code is as below,

```
"""
This is a simple application for sentence embeddings: semantic search

We have a corpus with various sentences. Then, for a given query sentence,
we want to find the most similar sentence in this corpus.

This script outputs for various queries the top 5 most similar sentences in the corpus.
"""
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util
import torch

embedder = SentenceTransformer('paraphrase-distilroberta-base-v1')

# Corpus with example sentences
corpus = ind_type_new['Industry_type_new_list'].to_list()
corpus_embeddings = embedder.encode(corpus, convert_to_tensor=True)

# Query sentences:
queries = df_test['industry_types_test'][df_test['industry_types_test'] != ''].head(50)

# Find the closest 5 sentences of the corpus for each query sentence based on cosine similarity
top_k = min(1, len(corpus))
for query in queries:
    query_embedding = embedder.encode(query, convert_to_tensor=True)

    # We use cosine-similarity and torch.topk to find the highest 5 scores
    cos_scores = util.pytorch_cos_sim(query_embedding, corpus_embeddings)[0]
    top_results = torch.topk(cos_scores, k=top_k)

    print("\n\n======================\n\n")
    print("Query:", query)
    print("\nTop 5 most similar sentences in corpus:")

    for score, idx in zip(top_results[0], top_results[1]):
        print(corpus[idx], "(Score: {:.4f})".format(score))
```

***The output of the code is as below***

```
======================


Query: Farming

Top 5 most similar sentences in corpus:
Agriculture (Score: 0.4851)
Construction (Score: 0.4436)
Manufacturing (Score: 0.4099)
Property (Score: 0.3876)
Importer (Score: 0.3616)


======================


Query: Shopping Centre 

Top 5 most similar sentences in corpus:
Consumer Services (Score: 0.4105)
Hospitality (Score: 0.4089)
Business Services (Score: 0.3898)
Wholesale / Distribution (Score: 0.3863)
Retail (Score: 0.3625)


======================


Query: Retail Food

Top 5 most similar sentences in corpus:
Retail (Score: 0.7708)
Consumer Services (Score: 0.4168)
Accommodation and Food Services (Score: 0.4085)
Business Services (Score: 0.3977)
Insurance (Score: 0.3870)
```

As you can see it gives the top 5 best scores, I want the text with top 1 best score and it should be an additional column in my dataframe df_test.
What changes I'm I supposed to make?

I have tried

```
top_k=1 #because we only want the top match
for query in queries:
    query_embedding = embedder.encode(query, convert_to_tensor=True)
    cos_scores = util.pytorch_cos_sim(query_embedding, corpus_embeddings)[0]
    top_results = torch.topk(cos_scores, k=top_k)
    df_test.at[query, "Match"] = corpus[int(top_results[1])] #save the result to your df
```

That did give me a "Match" column but its all NaN values. Only time its not NaN is when the rest of the dataframe is empty.

Sample output should look like this
[image]

Comment: I'm using python 3.x

Comment: Please fix your formatting in your first code block

Comment: Can you please suggest? I have primitive knowledge in python. I found that code in a semantic search website and used it.

Comment: I would first learn how to use python and learn how to program a lot more before you start machine learning algorithms. Also, please add three `"""` at the start of the first code block.

Comment: I've added it. Can you please suggest what amends I need to make to the for loop to add another column which is the best match?

Comment: From the information of you having "primitive knowledge" I assume you only know basic stuff: functions, variables, types, etc. PyTorch is a machine learning library. You will need to know [tag:numpy] and advanced knowledge on the basic info I listed earlier. This is just a recommendation though. It is not required

Comment: I'm in the process of learning. Can you please suggest what changes I need to make to the for loop to get an additional column?

Comment: Wait, do you want an additional column or the top1 best score printed only?

Comment: I want the additional column which has the word with the best score. For example, the row which has Farming should have Agriculture next to it. Because Agriculture is the best matching (top score) Synonym for Farming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used pytorch, but I'm assuming that you can just get the max score of each query, then print it out afterwards.

```py
top_k = min(1, len(corpus))
top_industries = []
for query in queries:
    query_embedding = embedder.encode(query, convert_to_tensor=True)

    # We use cosine-similarity and torch.topk to find the highest 5 scores
    cos_scores = util.pytorch_cos_sim(query_embedding, corpus_embeddings)[0]
    top_results = torch.topk(cos_scores, k=top_k)

    max_score = max(zip(top_results[0], top_results[1]), key=lambda s:s[0])

    top_industries.append(corpus[max_score[1]])

df_test = df_test.assign(Match=pd.Series(top_industries))
```

Printing `max_score` should return the best matching synonym in the column.
You also just have to add a new column via [`DataFrame.assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html#pandas.DataFrame.assign) and [`Series()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html#pandas.Series)

Comment: No, that's not what I want. 

All I want to do is get another column in the 1st dataframe, which would be the best matching synonym for that column when compared with the 2nd dataframe.

For example the result would look like

Farming ---------------------- Agriculture

Shopping centre -------------- Consumer Services

I have 70k distinct industry types in df_test['industry_types_test']. 
ind_type_new['Industry_type_new_list'] has 20 distinct values. 
The 70k distinct rows will now have the best matching industry type in 20 distinct values.

Comment: @Manikanta Can you put a formatted expected output in your question so that I can  understand exactly what you want a little bit better. Comment formatting is hardly understandable unfortunately.

Comment: @Manikanta Take a look at the updated answer. I think it answers what you want

Comment: I've updated the sample output in the question section. The dataframe has an additional 'Match' column

Comment: But how do I put Agriculture , Consumer Services, Consumer Services as a column in my main dataframe ? I want the best matching result -- max(score), the word that is best matching as a SEPERATE COLUMN in my dataframe df_test.

Comment: @Manikanta I do not know what the outline of `df_test` looks like and where the new column should go in the df. Can you explain where it should appear?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233304/discussion-between-manikanta-and-12944qwerty).

Comment: df_test looks like the sample output image that I've attached to the question (without Match column). Now I want the "'match'' column in df_test. which is the best match of the word from the column ind_type_new['Industry_type_new_list']

Comment: Can someone please answer this?